# MySQL - saving binary log to table by default

Tags: mysql, binary-log

I am using MySQL Community Server 5.1. I remember a while back I heard that it was possible to configure MySQL database to save the binary log information to a MySQL table.  I did a brief search and didn't come back with what I was looking for this time.  I would like to view all the info from the binary log right in some database table.  Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't save binary log to a table. That would defy its purpose.
General query log and slow query log on the other hand can be stored to table.